# Issue using NPM to install node-serialport

Tags: node.js, serial-port, npm

When I try to run NPM install serialport I get a failure with this error.  I am able to install other modules fine, just not serialport.  I am relatively inexperienced with linux,node, and npm and need some guidance on this issue.

This is the command that fails in the package.json

"cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../"

I have node Version 0.4.9 and NPM version 1.0.15 and was trying to install serialport version 0.2.8

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ npm install serialport

> serialport@0.2.8 install /home/administrator/node_modules/serialport
> cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../

sh: node-waf: not found
cp: cannot stat `build/default/serialport_native.node': No such file or directory
npm ERR! error installing serialport@0.2.8 Error: serialport@0.2.8 install: `cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../`
npm ERR! error installing serialport@0.2.8 `sh "-c" "cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../"` failed with 1
npm ERR! error installing serialport@0.2.8     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR! error installing serialport@0.2.8     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! error installing serialport@0.2.8     at ChildProcess.onexit (child_process.js:192:12)
npm ERR! serialport@0.2.8 install: `cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the serialport@0.2.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the serialport package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls serialport
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-8-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "serialport"
npm ERR! cwd /home/administrator
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.15
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/administrator/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the way, it seems the package binaries (at least in 10.10) changed from node-waf, to nodejs-waf.  If you're getting "Command not found" messages with "node-waf", try "nodejs-waf" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume [voodootikigod's serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport)

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/contact$ npm install serialport

> serialport@0.2.8 install /home/alfred/node_modules/serialport
> cd serialport_native;node-waf configure build;cp build/default/serialport_native.node ../

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : ok /home/alfred/.node_libraries 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /home/alfred/.nvm/v0.4.9 
'configure' finished successfully (0.555s)
Waf: Entering directory `/home/alfred/node_modules/serialport/serialport_native/build'
[1/2] cxx: serialport_native.cc -> build/default/serialport_native_1.o
../serialport_native.cc:11: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
[2/2] cxx_link: build/default/serialport_native_1.o -> build/default/serialport_native.node
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/alfred/node_modules/serialport/serialport_native/build'
'build' finished successfully (2.014s)
serialport@0.2.8 ../../node_modules/serialport 


alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/contact$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/contact$ node -v
v0.4.9
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/contact$ npm -v
1.0.15
```

Very strange if it does not install for you. You should output the complete error??

Comment: I added the full output above.

Comment: Strange node-waf is not in your path. I advice you to reinstall node. Maybe install it using nave => https://github.com/creationix/nvm. Also I run node as normal user, which is probably safer..

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem too on getting serialport2 to work with node.js 0.5.

Got serialport2 working after upgrade to node.js 0.8+